# Why does Python Request's JSON decoder return the concatenation of top-level keys

Tags: python, json, django, python-requests

I am using the Requests library to decode a JSON response as follows:

Payload Being Decoded:

```
{
    "objectOne": {
        "desc": "one"
    },
    "objectTwo": {
        "desc": "two"
    }
}
```

Code:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import requests

class ApiService:
    @staticmethod
    def say_something(self):
        resp = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:9501/polls/test/')

        return HttpResponse(resp.json())
```

Output:

objectOneobjectTwo

I followed the simple example from the official documentation:

[JSON Response Content](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content)

In addition I wrapped the response in `[]` brackets to see if the response must be in a JSON array but it just returns an array with 'objectOneobjectTwo' as the 1st and only element.

Comment: @Rawing: the example is there, and it'll produce the wrong output. But that's because the OP has misunderstood Django, and blames `requests`.

Comment: Side note: a `staticmethod()` doesn't take `self` as an argument. The actual object passed in is the Django `request` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misdiagnosed what is happening. `requests` is returning the correct dictionary. But you are passing a dictionary to `HttpResponse()`, without any further processing. However, `HttpResponse()` is **not set up to handle dictionaries**.

What happens is that `HttpResponse()` takes an *iterable* and will serve each value from the iterable as a string. In essence, you told Django to send **only the keys**, concatenated, to the client. From the [`HttpResponse()` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.__init__):

> **`content`** should be an iterator or a string. If it’s an iterator, it should return strings, and those strings will be joined together to form the content of the response.

and from the [`dict()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

> **`iter(d)`**
>   Return an iterator over the keys of the dictionary. This is a shortcut for `iter(d.keys())`.

If you wanted to send JSON data, use a [`JSONResponse()` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) instead. It is set up to encode Python objects correctly:

```
from django.http import JSONResponse
import requests


def say_something(request):
    resp = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:9501/polls/test/')

    return JSONResponse(resp.json())
```

or don't bother with decoding and re-encoding, just pass on the original response data:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import requests


def say_something(request):
    resp = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:9501/polls/test/')

    return HttpResponse(resp.text, resp.headers['content-type'])
```

Note: I removed the class and `staticmethod` decorator; there is little point in wrapping static view functions in a class when no state is shared. Use modules to create namespaces instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is a JSON object, which is parsed into a Python dictionary. HttpResponse expects an iterable, which it iterates through when returning the response upstream; usually you pass a string (ie the result of rendering a template), but here you pass a dictionary. Iterating through a dictionary gives the keys only.

If you want to show the full output, convert to a string first by passing `str(response.json())` - which of course is pointless since it will just be the same as the raw response.